# Removing namespace prefix while creating xml file in python

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml-namespaces, elementtree

I am creating an XML file in python.
The first element is built as follows:

```
xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
mainElement = ET.Element("{" +xsi+ "}ArrayOfAnyType")
```

which results in a line:

```
<xsi:ArrayOfAnyType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

What I cannot solve is how to remove the xsi prefix in "xsi:Array...".
The rest of the created xml file is just as I need.

Thanks for your hints

Piotr

Comment: you want a string like this: `<ArrayOfAnyType xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">` ?

Comment: Exactly. That's how I want it.

Comment: To add more information, I cannot use ET.tostring, so I cannot replace the prefix with empty string. I waas rather thinking of some solution within ET.Element creation.

Comment: Try [using XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816252/xslt-remove-namespace-prefix-from-elements), it is [supported in lxml](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#xslt)